# Could we improve the visibility of links

Tags: feature-request, design

The color on links is, fitting to the site design, red. 
As somone suffering from red–green color blindness, which isn't rarely (depending on origin up to 10%), it's hard for me to spot links on Askubuntu.
Many of the better made (seemingly answering the question) spam posts, hiding a promotional link somewhere in the text are hard to detect for me.

The request would be to make links more prominent. I'm not asking to change the color but maybe we could display them  e.g. cursive, fat or underlined.

Comment: The links do have underlines on hover, but I think your case is best handled using a user script (like with Stylish or Greasemonkey) which styles anchor tags to be bold or something. Have a look at how other people site design they don't like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210041/270345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meantime, following muru's suggestion I created (with a bit of help from jokerdino♦ and Seth♦) a userscript which underlines all the links on askubuntu.com:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://askubuntu.com/*
// @match        http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

$('a').css({"text-decoration": "underline"});
```

The result is pretty good.

To install it simply install Greasemonkey (Firefox / Firefox derivatives) or Tampermonkey (Chrome / Chromium), add the script and enable it.

Known bugs:

- It doesn't work for content loaded after the page was loaded the first time (new active questions, edits etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect. I still would appreciate a "native" solution for those who are not used to or willing to install a userscript.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a user script, I highly recommend using an addon like [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/). This works on Firefox, not sure if there is a similar extension for Chrome.

After you install the addon, you can then manually edit the styles of a website based on your needs. (If you are familiar with CSS, then this I highly recommend the addon as it allows you to edit the styles of any website you visit that you are having difficulty with)

After you install it and restart Firefox, the stylish addon adds a toolbar icon. Click it and choose "Write new style".
If you choose "For askubuntu.com" from the submenu, any styles you write, will be implemented for the askubuntu.com domain and any of its subdomains like meta.askubuntu.com and www.askubuntu.com (This can be changed later on).

Anyway, after you choose one of the domain options, you will get something similar to this:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("meta.askubuntu.com") {

}
```

Just add the following style inside the curly brackets:

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

The resulting code would be the following:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com") {
  a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
  }
}
```

Give your style a name and save. And voilà, you have underlined links everywhere in the askubuntu sites.